# Finding groups of IP addresses in a file

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a file with groups of IP addresses. The file looks like this:

```
London:
1.1.1.0-1.1.1.200
172.25.2.0-172.25.2.100
Germany:
2.2.2.0-2.2.2.100
192.168.1.0-192.168.1.200
172.25.2.0-172.25.2.200
```

So when I search for an IP address (`./program.sh 172.25.2.32` ) the output should be London and Germany.

Comment: Well that what im trying to figure out how to do it. Searching with grep and other filters not working ... I dont have code for now that way i ask the question. Some hints on how to do it.

Comment: You don't need grep for that, you just need a two line executable bash script. Line 1: `!#/bin/bash`. Line 2: `if [ x$1 == x172.25.2.32 ] ; then echo -e "London\nGermany"; fi`

Comment: @Anthon a friend of mine used to say that everything can be solved with two lines of perl, and the first one is always `#!/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: @pqnet and a Stéphane's answer shows your friend could be right. I personally got my fill of one-liners with APL back in the early 80s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't accepted the other solutions, maybe because their output doesn't match the requested "London and Germany"

Modern Python can handle IP addresses out of the box:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3.4
# coding: utf-8
# also works on 2.7 after installing ipaddress from PyPI

import sys
from ipaddress import ip_address
print

ip_string = sys.argv[1]
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    ip_string = ip_string.decode('utf-8')

ip = ip_address(ip_string)

locs = []
for line in open('input'):
    try:
        loc, rest = line.split(':')
    except ValueError:
        try:
            if sys.version_info < (3,):
                sr, er = map(ip_address, [x.decode('utf-8') for x in line.rstrip().split('-')])
            else:
                sr, er = map(ip_address, line.rstrip().split('-'))
            if sr < ip < er:
                locs.append(loc)
        except ValueError:
            print 'error in input line:', repr(line)
            break

if len(locs) > 2:
    locs = [', '.join(locs[:-1]), locs[-1]]
print(' and '.join(locs))
```

This prints the found locations and puts "`and`" between the last two locations found and "`,`" between all others (when applicable): e.g. `London, Paris and Germany`

The data is assumed to be in a file called `input`, make the script executable, or call with `python scriptname 172.25.2.32`

Comment: I have the following error when i execute. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ipaddress import ip_address
ImportError: No module named ipaddress
`

Comment: @user3523605 Then you are running this with Python version < 3.3. You can try to use a Python3 interpreter (`python3`) if installed on your system, or alternatively install [ipaddress from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress/1.0.6) using your package manager (if availble there, `pip` or `easy_install`

Comment: Hi i have installed the module but iv got this error now `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 6, in <module>
    ip = ip_address(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
`

Comment: @use That is most likely because you did not provide an IP address as the argument to the invoked script: `python yourscriptname 172.25.2.32`. The `sys.argv[1]` accesses the first argument to the script sys.argv[0] is the name of the script itself.

Comment: Hi yes i saw that and still trying to figure out on this next error i have `# cat input 
Lonodon:
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
Germany:
4.4.4.4
2.2.2.2
6.6.6.6
172.32.28.1
# python test3.py 172.28.3.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 6, in <module>
    ip = ip_address(sys.argv[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipaddress.py", line 113, in ip_address
    ' a unicode object?' % address)
ipaddress.AddressValueError: '172.28.3.1' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object? 
`

Comment: @user3523605 I updated the script in the answer. It should now work with Python 2.7 as well as 3.3/3.4

Comment: Ye im using Ubuntu but still have errors. Am i missing some arguments or ? `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 21, in <module>
    sr, er = map(ip_address, [x.decode('utf-8') for x in line.rstrip().split('-')])
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
` I'm execute like this `python test3.py 2.2.2.2`

Comment: There must be an error in your input file, for me that command `python test.py 2.2.2.2` works. I have added another `try` statement that prints out the line that goes wrong. I need what the program prints there. BTW Maybe we should continue this in a chat session, program help is a bit out of the scope of this Q&A site.

Comment: Yes that will be better ... but how to go on chat session from here or you mean skype or something like that ?

Comment: I have now with the try add new error `error in input line: '1.1.1.1\n'` and i execute like this: `python test4.py 2.2.2.2`

Comment: Hey It works i have messed up the input file i have right the ips like one ips not in range ... just 1.1.1.1 new line 2.2.2.2 etc ... this is my mistake sorry ... but it will be good if it works or to make a new one with just one ip not a range

Comment: Just replace the line `print 'error ...` and the line `break` with a test for a single IP address.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using one of the many general-purpose programming languages that are usually available for Unix and Linux system (either as part of the default installation or via a simple package install) is probably the easiest.  Here is an example of how you would complete the task at hand using Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'ipaddr'

ip = ARGV[0]
ARGV.delete(ip)
last_location = nil
ARGF.each do |line|
  if line.include?(':')
    last_location = line.chomp.gsub(/:/, "")
    next
  end

  first, last = line.chomp.split("-").map {|i| IPAddr.new(i).to_i }
  needle = IPAddr.new(ip).to_i
  if (first..last).include?(needle)
    puts "Found #{ip} in #{last_location}"
  end
end
```

This isn't particularly *good* Ruby, but it is able to take advantage of the `ipaddr` library to avoid manually parsing IP addresses.  While manual processing wouldn't be a big deal in your example text, it would be more difficult when you had ranges such as 172.25.2.0-172.25.3.200.

Your question is tagged `bash` and `text-processing`.  If you are looking for an answer using the more widely available text-processing tools such as sed, awk, and grep, then you might want to just look at the general strategy contained in the ruby script above:

1. Store the IP address argument in a variable for easy access later
2. Read each line of the file
3. Determine if the line is a location description or IP address range.
4. If it is a location description, store it in last_location
5. If it is an ip address range, determine if your IP is in that range
6. If the ip is in the range, print out the last_location variable.

It isn't the most elegant solution, but it is one that is straight-forward to implement in a number of languages and would be easy to follow by anyone familiar with the language.

Answer (score 2):

`perl` version of [Steven's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153123/22565):

```
perl -MSocket -F- -lane '
  sub ip_to_n {unpack"N",inet_aton$_[0]}
  BEGIN {$i=ip_to_n(shift)}
  if (/:$/) {chop;$l=$_} else {
    print $l if $i >= ip_to_n($F[0]) && $i <= ip_to_n($F[1])
  }' 172.25.2.32 file1 file2...
```